# Asp.net web from application does not run in IIS

Tags: iis-7.5

I am going to deploy a web from application in windows server 2016 and IIS . But when I deploy it onn IIS it shows all directory in browser instead of running my application. When I disable directory browsing, in browser It shows 403 not found .
What should I do now to live my project on IIS  ??

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-asp-net-modules

Answer (score 0):

The reason you only see the page for directory browsing is that you have not set a default page for your application.

Follow the steps below to set the default page for your web application:

1.Find the Defualt Document and double click it.
[image]

2.Enter the page you want to display:

[image]

3.Finally browse your application and jump directly to your default page.